# additional brake lever as bullhorn lever

Tags: brake-levers, bullhorn

I want to change the handlebar on my folding bike, to get a less upright position.
My idea is to pu a bullhorn-like bar, but I need both cable brake, and right shifter. Thus, I have either to use a bar-end brake and clamp shifter, or the other way around.

I am not sure which I will chose. The trouble with bar-end brakes is that the housing goes inside the bar, and drill the bars scares me (or else drill if close to the lever).

As clamp bar lever, I have found this kind of additional levers:

[image]

On the picture we see the housing with barrel, but on a bullhorn it might go in the opposite direction (lije the cable from the main lever on the picture).
It seems to me that the cable could run from the barrel, backwards. Is that a stupid idea ?

Comment: Where did you get the idea that bar end levers put the cable inside the bar? All that I have seen put it under the bar wrap, similar to interrupter levers in the picture.

Comment: I have seen that on at least one model (sorry, I do not remember which one) and as I did not see other information on other models, I  guessed it was the more common way. It is good news if I am wrong. In commercial websites, information are often missing, and I did not see detailes pictures on bar-end levers. Okay, I will also look that way, thank you.

Comment: For example, the Tektro TL720 levers have an internal routing. The Cane creek 200TT not.

Comment: This question is not able to answered without knowing what pull of brake levers is needed (long or short) and what shifter type is needed.

Comment: Pull is not really a problem for the brake, The bike has mini V-brake, so short-pull, but I could also use regular V-brakes. The shifter will be a 10 speed MTB (Shimano derailleur). For this, I will try to find a microshift thumb shifter, tht exists in clamp and bar-end version (but not that easy to get)